# h:graphicimage not working in c:foreach

Tags: java, jsf, foreach, jstl

I have used c:forEach loop for display the list of images using h:graphicImage. But I can't display the images. I have the h:commandLink also in my page. The image have to be displayed at the time of form inititalization. But its not working. But after click the h:commandlink, the images are displayed properly. Before that it shows the image not found text (alt message). I have used h:graphicImage tag like below

```
<c:forEach items="#{Sample.imageList}" var="images" varstatus="imageStatus">
    <h:graphicimage id="image" url="#{images}" alt="Image Not Found"/>
</c:forEach>
```

What I do wrong in that and how can I achieve that?

Comment: Do you have to use jstl? Try using <ui:repeat> to see if you get the same behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image URL is relative to the URL in the browser address bar. Apparently the commandlink was forwarded to an URL which made the relative image URL's valid.

To fix this problem, you need to know the *absolute* URL (starting with http://) of the images and the *absolute* URL of the page in question. Then you can extract the right relative URL for the image from this and use this in `h:graphicImage`.

Comment: Hi Balusc,Thx for your answer.But now i got the new issue.By default i run the application its contains the applicationcontextname in the path.After i perform any operation its also add the applicationcontext in the relative path.So i can't get my image.HOw can i resolve this issue?Please help me.

Comment: Hi BalusC,Thx for your reply.I have been stuck with this problem.By your answer i can resolve this issue.Thk once again.

Comment: What's the absolute URL of the image and the page?

Comment: Hi Balusc,Absolute url of the image is http://localhost:8084/sample/sample-images/Home/image1.jpg.Absolute Url of page is http://localhost:8084/sample/faces/pages/general/main.jsp.

Comment: So the relative URL of the image is `../../../sample-images/Home/image1.jpg`. Better is to use `/sample/sample-images/Home/image1.jpg`. If `#{images}` resolves to `image1.jpg`, then you need to specify `/sample/sample-images/Home/#{images}` as URL.